# Is it possible to edit a part of the date only in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, date

To create a date, I use this :

```
$date = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
$insert = date('Y-m-d h:i:sa',$date);
```

When I insert, I insert a day with only the day, and I collect the month later. Is it possible, with SQL and Date PHP to update the column in my database?

I would like to update the `date_deb` column, but just the month in the date format.

Here is my structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `DateTest` (
`id_date` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` text NOT NULL,
  `date_deb` DATE NOT NULL,
  `date_fin` DATE DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html or have you been through that already?

Comment: I don't really understand this doc :/ I know how function update query, and I use it when necessary, but this is for change the value of a column, not a part of the value ?

Comment: `UPDATE table SET column_x = 'your_date' where column_y = '?'` - Hard to say at this point, you'll need to show us what your db schema looks like, including the row you wish to update and to what.

Comment: This is the structure of my db http://pastebin.com/DCmeaCBh 
And I would like to update the `date_deb` column, but just the month in the date format

Comment: thanks but that isn't enough; my comment was a 2-part question. Please post the values (in your question) that you presently have in your table and what you wish to change row(s) to.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE DateTest 
SET date_deb = (SELECT ADDDATE(date_deb, 31) 
FROM DateTest 
WHERE id_date = 'somevalue');
```

Maybe something like that.  I didn't test this.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate

Comment: I'll try this with my examples, and go back to say if it works :) Thanks for help